# On this question test a categorical syllogism to determine whether it is valid or invalid please explain in detail thanks

Tags: logic

All ranchers who own large estates are people who own guns, therefore All people who hunt are people who own guns, since All ranchers who own large estates are people who hunt.

Comment: The argument is invalid because of a concept called distribution. The conclusion of the argument has a distributed term that is not distributed in the premises. In this way the argument commits a logical fallacy. Your textbook should go over distribution of terms. You can even look online about logical distribution if you are not familiar. Once you understand distribution this question type is hard to get wrong. Note deductive reasoning is not about the content of the argument given. Do not try to understand sentences. You are to study FORM and not the content of the subject matter.

Answer (score 1):

From a set theory point of view, let:

R = {x: x is a rancher}

G = {x: x owns a gun}

H = {x: x hunts}

E = {x in R: x owns a large estate}

"All ranchers who own large estates are people who own guns" <-> E lies within G

"All ranchers who own large estates are people who hunt" <-> E lies within H

But that does not mean H lies within G.  We have not said anything that relates these two.

So we do not know whether "All people who hunt are people who own guns"

Answer (score 0):

1. All ranchers who own large estates are people who own guns. (All M are P)
2. All ranchers who own large estates are people who hunt. (All M are S)

Conclusion: All people who hunt are people who own guns. (All S are P)

The syllogism is invalid. The minor term (people who hunt) is distributed in the conclusion but not in the premises. The technical name for the problem is "illicit minor".